# Salesforce internal server error - SSO through OAuth 2.0 external provider

Tags: apex, oauth2, single-sign-on, auth-provider, external-app

I am configuring **Single Sign On** for my application through **OAuth 2.0** server.
I used the next recommendations:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm&type=5#plugin_setup

Following this link I created my custom Auth. Provider which uses:
1. CustomPlugin extends **Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass**
2. CustomRegistrationHandler implements **Auth.RegistrationHandler**

Provider contains **Test-Only Initialization URL** and **Single Sign-On Initialization URL**.
When I send a request using the **Test-Only Initialization URL** I get a response with **UserData** in xml format:
[image]

It means that interactions between salesforce and my OAuth server work as expected.

Then I try to use **Single Sign-On Initialization URL**. The response is the next:

[image]

I tried to debug my **Plugin** and **RegistrationHandler** classes.
It looks likes **Plugin** is correct.

Logs for **RegistrationHandler** operation name is **RegistrationHandlerUserUpdate**(even if I log in external app as a new user - why update and not create?).
I have **System.debug('message)** at the first string of every method(**create/update** and canCreate).

**Debug level** is relevant(I use the same debug level in Plugin debug and I see such messages in Plugin logs).

But I don't see these messages in **RegistrationHandler** logs.

**RegistrationHandler debug logs ends with:**

[image]

Could you give me a hint how I can resolve it?

Comment: If you are not getting anything in the Plugin implementation and that this is an internal error, you may need to reach out to Salesforce support for this. As for the logs for registration handler, the logs do show it as "RegistrationHandlerUserUpdate" but it will print accurately if the flow went to `create` vs. `update`. Also one thing to note is that, `create` is called only once, very first time when you authenticate the user, and thereafter its always the `update`.

Comment: @JayantDas All registration handler examples show for create: create contact, create user with contactId. For update: update user. But contact contain user LastName and FirstName, why don't we update contacts?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked:

UserData should contains at least an empty Map of attributes(the last paramter in constructor). Otherwise you will recieve Internal Server error.

Comment: I was running into the same and putting an empty Map<String, String> in the attributeMap part of the Auth.UserInfo solved this. But it sounds like something that Salesforce should be able to handle on their side of the framework.

Comment: @Folkert I fully agreed